# Writing a function to convert hex to decimal

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to write a function that converts hex to decimal and I've got an idea of how to do it but I'm stuck at the first bit. So far I am taking the user input and returning it in hex, but this only works if I enter 1 thing at a time. The code is:

```
def hex(x):
    if x == "0":
        return 0
    elif x == "1":
        return 1
    elif x == "2":
        return 2
    elif x == "3":
        return 3
    elif x == "4":
        return 4    
    elif x == "5":
        return 5
    elif x == "6":
        return 6
    elif x == "7":
        return 7
    elif x == "8":
        return 8
    elif x == "9":
        return 9
    elif x == "A":
        return 10
    elif x == "B":
        return 11
    elif x == "C":
        return 12
    elif x == "D":
        return 13
    elif x == "E":
        return 14
    elif x == "F":
        return 15

print hex(raw_input().upper())
```

It works if I enter, for example, C then it returns 12, but if I enter 8C then it doesn't work. I can't figure out why this is.

Comment: If `x` is equal to the string `8C`, which branch of your big `if ... elif` statement do you think will be taken? If you can answer that then you will have figured out why your code doesn't work.

Comment: You need to call your `hex()` function for _each character in the user input_; and then collect and print the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `int` to make this a lot easier. Function:

```
def hex_to_dex(strng_of_hex):
    return int(strng_of_hex, 16)
```

Example:

```
>>> int("0xff", 16)
255
```

It does not matter if you have a `0x` infront for int, it will ignore `0x` in the string. So, the following will also work:

```
>>> int("a", 16)
10
```

As for a raw hex code from scratch, try the following:

```
def hex(s):
    _hexer = "0123456789ABCDEF"
    return sum([_hexer.find(var) * 16 ** i for i, var in enumerate(reversed(s.upper()))])
```

If you wanted to put some guards in:

```
def hex(s):
    _hexer = "0123456789ABCDEF"

    if not all([var in _hexer for var in s.upper()]):
        print "Invalid string"
        return None

    return sum([_hexer.find(var) * 16 ** i for i, var in enumerate(reversed(s.upper()))])
```

I've used a lot of functions here, but for quick reference, here's an appendix:

1. [str.find](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)
2. [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html#pep-279-enumerate)
3. [reversed](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) -> reverses the string
4. [sum](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)

As for the `[...]`, its a list comprehension, you can find loads of resources on that.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to write my own function to do this. I am going to do it by taking the length of the input string, and multiplying the first number by 16 to the power of length minus 1.

Comment: @JaAnTr Tr the latest addition.

Comment: `sum()` is the wrong function here. The `_hexer.find()` trick is cute, but the resulting value will be very wrong.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It will? let me test it some more.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: Try `C8`. That should return 200; yours returns 20; `(12 * 16) + 8`, not `12 + 8`.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: Btw, `_hexer = dict(map(reversed, enumerate("0123456789ABCDEF")))` or similar would be even cuter ;-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Could you see if that works for you? Just made some edits.

Comment: @SteveJessop You're right, it looks awesome :)

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: That last revision works.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: now replace the inefficient `.find()` with a dictionary and you are all set. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks so much for guiding me :) We should have coffees sometime.

Comment: There's another remaining question: how to deal with invalid input. `_hexer.find('X')` is `-1`, so this function returns a wrong value. That's fine if someone else is responsible for correctness of the input, but `index('X')` would throw an exception, which might be more useful. Similar issue with a dictionary, whether to use `[var]` or `get(var, -1)`.

Comment: @SteveJessop You really like that dict, don't ya? Well, I won't copy it since its not mine. But I will put in some guards.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but I'm trying to test your raw hex code by adding `print hex(input())` and it's not working. I've also tried replacing `input` with `raw_input` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @JaAnTr http://ideone.com/rqqzyB

Comment: @JaAnTr If I've answered your question, please do accept.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Thanks, I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are passing the entire string the user inputs to your hex function. Because of this it works for 'C' but not for '8C'. You aren't checking for '8C' in your if statements.
Therefor your hex function returns with the value `None`.
In order to prevent this you need to pass the user inputted string to your hex function one character at a time.

assuming:

```
values = raw_input().upper()
```

and using your `hex()` function as defined in your question.
you could:

```
print([hex(v) for v in values])
```

or if you don't want a list:

```
print(' '.join([str(hex(v)) for v in values]))
```

This uses the function you defined but applies it to all characters the user inputs... instead of just the first one.

*This answer works under the assumption that you are happy with the current functionality and return types of your defined `hex()` function.*

Comment: "but if I enter 8C then it doesn't work." I'm showing an explanation for this. He is apparently happy with the existing functionality "It works if I enter, for example, C"

Comment: this uses his defined hex() the one in the question.

Comment: Ah, then it's still a problem because `hex()` returns integers. Turning that into strings is not going to produce the desired output; `C8` will result in `128`, not `200`.

Comment: @RMcG: ah, I see, sorry. I thought you were proposing a *replacement* for the questioner's `hex` function!

Comment: @SteveJessop No problem, I should have made it more apparent.

Comment: @Martinjn The defined hex function returns integers and string, converting the string 'C' and integer 8 into a string will results in "C8".